# Associating a shipping address model with an order model Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I'm trying to associate a shipping address with an order in my application but cannot figure out a good way to do this.

This is the association I have:

```
class ShippingAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

and

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address
end
```

I see a lot of examples assuming there is a current_user, but I am trying to make the checkout process so that a user does not have to be signed in.

Here is what my Shipping Addresses controller looks like:

```
class ShippingAddressesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @shipping_address = ShippingAddress.new
    end

    def create
        @shipping_address = ShippingAddress.new(shipping_address_params)
            @shipping_address.save 
            redirect_to root_url
    end

    private

    def shipping_address_params
      params.require(:shipping_address).permit(:shipping_name, :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_city, 
        :address_state, :address_zip, :address_country, :user_id, :order_id)
    end
end
```

This is what the order controller looks like:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(item_id: params[:order][:item_id], order_completed: false, user_id: params[:order][:user_id])
    @order.update_attribute(:quantity_requested, params[:order][:quantity_requested])
    @order.save
    redirect_to @order
  end 
private 
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :item_id, :quantity_requested, :quantity, 
      :order_completed, :sold, :shipping_address_id)
  end
end
```

Can someone please let me know if I'm thinking about this the right way and how I can make the order aware of the shipping address?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really need a `:user_id` in parameters. If user is logged in, you can get it via `current_user`. If not, you'll never know his id anyway.

Order is aware of the shipping address when you create it like `order.create_shipping_address` or `ShippingAddress.create order: order` (or populate `shipping_addresses.order_id` field any other way you like). And then you can use `order.shipping_address` and `shipping_address.order` to find related objects.

Also, usually managers(or site) have to communicate with customer anyway, at least send some emails regarding order status, so I don't require user to log in, but if he is not logged in, I create a new one on checkout to store his contacts(and for some other useful stuff :) )

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments and feedback.  I've tried putting your suggestions and I'm still missing something.  I'm not quite sure where you meant for me to put order.create_shipping_address.  Should this go in the order controller or the address controller?  I've tried several ways and get different error messages depending on the way I work it.

Comment: @Kelly, I missed the fact that you already pass `:order_id` when you create a shipping address. At least it is in `shipping_address_params`. So if it is really sent, than You can just skip the first part of what I've written and go straight to the part where `order.shipping_address` and `shipping_address.order` are :)  `order.shipping_address` should return shipping address associated with order and `shipping_address.order` returns order associated with shipping address.

Comment: Going back to the first part of my suggestions, it was meant to be like `order=Order.find :order.id         @shipping_address=order.create_shipping_address shipping_address_ params` in `shipping_addresses_controller#create` instead of `        @shipping_address = ShippingAddress.new(shipping_address_params) @shipping_address.save `